# Every compact connected Lie group is actually a real algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups

> Every compact connected Lie group is actually a real algebraic group.

For example $U(n)$ fits the requests. I can't understand in which sense $U(n)$ is real, since its matrices are not real and its defining equations are not real.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your question why is this theorem true?  Or why is $U(n)$ a real algebraic group?

Comment: I don't know the full details of this.  But if you can realize your Lie group $G$ as the rational points of an algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$, then you can realize them as the points of a group over $\mathbb{R}$.  Let $G = \mathbf G(\mathbb{C})$ for some algebraic group $\mathbf G$ over $\mathbb{C}$.  There is a construction of an algebraic group $\mathbf H = \textrm{Res}_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}(\mathbf G)$ over $\mathbb{R}$, called the *restriction of scalars*, for which you can canonically identify $\mathbf H(\mathbb R) = \mathbf G(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Also, every compact, connected, complex Lie group is isomorphic to the cartesian product of an algebraic torus and a semisimple Lie group, modulo a finite normal subgroup.  From here, you can deduce that such a group must be linear.

Comment: Actually, restriction of scalars is pretty intuitive here.  Your group is defined by the zeroes of a bunch of polynomial equations in $\mathbb{C}^{n^2+1}$ space for some $n$.  But then you can just think of your group as a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^{2n^2 + 2}$, so it naturally acquires the structure of a real manifold.

Answer (score 4):

$U(n)$ is a real algebraic group, and not a complex algebraic group, because the equations which define it are algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$, and not over $\mathbb{C}$.

Consider
$$
   U(1) = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid z \bar z = 1\right\}
$$
In this form $U(1)$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^\times$, so is a group of complex numbers.  And the equation defining $U(1)$ has complex variables in it.  But that equation is not a polynomial equation in $z$, because of the $\bar z$ term.

On the other hand, $U(1)$ is isomorphic to the group
$$
    S^1 = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1 \right\}
$$
with multiplication rule given by
$$
    (x_1,y_1)\cdot(x_2,y_2) = (x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2, x_1 y_2 + y_1 x_2)
$$
Now the group's equation is a polynomial in the real variables $x$ and $y$.